# How do we identify if an org is using NPSP

Tags: apex, nonprofit-starter-pack

We are developing an appexchange product and there is a functionality which needs to be different if its a Non profit vs the rest of the licenses.  Is there a way we can identify if the org uses NPSP?

Thanks

Comment: I submitted the above because the NPSP is series of managed packages, so you should be able to use the answers in that question to test for it.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMasterson.. That was exactly what i was looking for, but i am not sure if we could categorize as a duplicate question. I would leave it to the community to close the question or leave it as it is.